# What is the correct way of counting every column by itself in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, exadata

I have a table which has several columns. Except customer column, I want to count them all by themselves. I need to see how many transactions done on "value1" by "customer:100" in segment "1". Which is in this scenario at the bottom, answer is 2.

| customer | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 100 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 101 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 101 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 101 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |

I need something like this:

| customer | columns | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | value1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | value2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | value3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | value4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | value5 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | value1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | value2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | value3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 101 | value4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 101 | value5 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

But I wonder what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are values 6, 7, and 8?

Answer (score 0):

`UNPIVOT` the columns and then `PIVOT` on the values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  value
  FOR columns IN (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8)
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR value IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (customer, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8) AS
SELECT 100, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER | COLUMNS | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | VALUE1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | VALUE2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | VALUE3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | VALUE4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | VALUE5 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | VALUE6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 100 | VALUE7 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | VALUE8 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | VALUE1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | VALUE2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | VALUE3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 101 | VALUE4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 101 | VALUE5 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | VALUE6 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | VALUE7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | VALUE8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1LCi7vFO)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have 1 more question you have time. How can I call the last 5 columns by their names? You said Select * and they all came. Can I do something like SELECT CUSTOMER, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ? I failed to do so.

Comment: @süleyman Either use quoted identifiers `SELECT CUSTOMER, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"` or in the pivot clause give the columns aliases `FOR value IN (1 AS c1, 2 AS c2, 3 AS c3, 4 AS c4, 5 AS c5)` and then you can use unquoted identifiers with the aliases `SELECT CUSTOMER, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m8BY9Yty)